# Decode href URL link and Redirect Page with Vue.js after POST

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an example Vue.js setup of two pages. A list of products and then an order form.

https://listorder.netlify.com

ISSUE 1 - The URL passed from products to order page input gets encoded. I have tried to decode with decodeURI() but it still outputs encoded.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-pill" v-bind:href="'order.html?product=' + decodeURI(item.title) + '&' ?price=' + decodeURI(item.price)"  style="color:white;">Buy Now</a>
```

ISSUE 2 - After POST has completed, I need to redirect to a Paypal page appending data from the "Price" field on the order page. Not sure whether Vue will be required here or to add into the existing javascript.

Paypal page to redirect to `https://www.paypal.me/wereallcatshere/USD` then append the "price" field

JAVASCRIPT

```
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    showLoadingIndicator()
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form) })
        .then(response => showSuccessMessage(response))
        .catch(error => showErrorMessage(error))
})

function showSuccessMessage(response) {
    console.log('Success!', response)
    setTimeout(() => {
        successMessage.classList.remove('is-hidden')
        loading.classList.add('is-hidden')
    }, 500)
}
```

VUE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      items: []
    },
    created: function () {
      fetch('listorder.json')
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(items => {
          this.items = items;
        })
    },
    methods: {
      redirect: function () {
        window.location.href = "https://www.paypal.me/wereallcatshere/USD" + item.price;
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: please explain the scenario and what you want to get and what are you getting?

Comment: Hi BB, Currently getting encoded urls, I want these to be decoded. Secondly, I want to redirect after POST has completed to a external URL with the "item.price" appended to that URL. Please check the demo site to see the current encoded url and redirect issue

Comment: First off it's advisable to use Vue methods to handle form validations and submissions. Second you should avoid having to use native JavaScript event handlers in Vue components since you're using the Vue loader. Read more here https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/form-validation.html